# Would a solution to the Navier-Stokes Millennium Problem have any practical consequences?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes

I know the problem is especially of interest to mathematicians, but I was wondering if a solution to the problem would have any practical consequences.

Upon request: this is the official problem [description](http://www.claymath.org/millennium/Navier-Stokes_Equations/navierstokes.pdf) of the aforementioned problem.

Comment: A description of the challenge or links to the same would help here. I'm familiar with the Navier-Stokes equation, but not with this particular challenge. Others may be in the same boat.

Comment: The Clay description is awfully loose and allows many different formulations of the problem. [Terry Tao gave a pretty good description](http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.1165) of the various ways of formulating the Navier-Stokes Millennium Problem and their mutual implications.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is difficult to answer, because the answer depends on whether the answer is positive or negative. Although most people, including myself, expect a positive answer, a negative answer is actually possible, unlike say, for the question of P!=NP, or the well-definedness/mass-gap of gauge theory where we are 100% sure that we know the answer already (in the scientific, not in the mathematical sense).

If the answer is positive, if all Navier Stokes flows are smooth, then the proof will probably be of little practical consequence. It will need to provide a new regularity technique in differential equations, so it will probably be of great use in mathematics, but it will not be surprising to physics, who already expect smoothness from the known approximate statistical falloff of turbulence.

At short distances, the powerlaw falloff in turbulence turns into an exponential falloff, in the dissipative regime, so that the high k modes are suppressed by exponentials in k, and this implies smoothness. So smoothness is the expected behavior. This doesn't provide a proof, because the k-space analysis is too gross-- it is over the entire system. To prove the smoothness locally, my opinion is that you need a wavelet version of the argument.

On the other hand, if there are blow ups in Navier Stokes in finite time, these are going to be strange configurations with very little dissipation which reproduce themselves in finite time at smaller scales. Such a solution might be useful for something conceivably, because it might allow you to find short distance hot-spots in a turbulent fluid, where there are near-atomic-scale velocity gradients, and this could concievably be useful for something (although I can't imagine what). Also, such solution techniques would probably be useful for other differential equations to find scaling type solitons.

So it is hard to say without knowing from which direction the answer will come.

Comment: Two additional notes: (a) one possibly useful implication of the *instability* of Navier Stokes flow would be the following "really bad case scenario": Navier Stokes admits blow-up in finite time for a dense set of initial data, but also admits smooth global solutions for a dense set of initial data. This would basically tell you that any hope of numerically modelling nature using the Navier-Stokes equation is lost. (b) In regards to Ron's second to last paragraph, I would say in fact that blow up will suggest a physical regime where the NS equations are not applicable, and hence points to

Comment: where one should look for new physics. Perhaps even giving a clue on how to partially resolve Hilbert's sixth problem (at least the version that studies the derivation from Newtonian mechanics of the fluid equations).

Comment: @Willie: I don't think that blowups, even if dense, could ever be a real problem, because the NS equations have a scale-separation property due to Galilean invariance. Even if there are little hot-spots where the fluid gets singular, it would just be advected by the average flow. The mean velocity profile in k-space will definitely be powerlaw in the inertial regime, and exponential in the viscous regime, so it will be _mostly_ smooth, in the sense that any singularities will be isolated and tiny and will not affect numerical simulations. This is born out by both experiment and simulation.

Comment: As far as deriving the fluid equations, they are just momentum conservation, the only thing you need to derive is the constitutive viscosity relation, and the derivation is good-enough for physicists today. It might not be good enough for mathematicians, but I am not sure what the issues are exactly. When you have a fluid with bulk velocity field v, the bulk stress tensor must be $\rho v^iv^j + P \delta^{ij}$, and the pressure maintains $\nabla \cdot p$, and then incompressible Euler equations follow. The NS viscosity term is just the leading correction. What else is left to show?

Comment: @Willie: Also, a minor technical point: you say "dense", but dense is not a problem if it is measure zero. The rationals are dense, but if blowups require some Reynolds number to be exactly rational, nobody would think those are real observable blowups. Perhaps you meant that both smooth and blow-uppy solutions are of finite measure, but that's exceedingly unlikely.

Comment: @RonMaimon: dense in the *topology of space of initial conditions*, not dense in physical space. In other words, it could be conceivable that given any initial data, there are blow-up solutions that differ from it in arbitrarily small ways. In particular, the (global) Navier-Stokes flow can be completely discontinuous with regards to initial data.

Comment: @RonMaimon: derivation *from a bunch of particles bumping into each other*; in other words, trying to see how fluids arise from large particle limit of Newtonian mechanics. Going from molecular dynamics to a kinetic theory was only partially resolved after the work of Lanford in 1975 (see [this write-up by Uchiyama](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.hmj/1206129724)). And going from kinetic theory to fluids is still work in progress by, among others, Laure Saint-Raymond and collaborators.

Comment: Just one last comment: you say "born out by both experiment and simulation". But neither of those proves anything! If Navier-Stokes is actually **not** the complete picture of physical fluids, experiments won't tell you anything about where NS precisely fails to describe actual physics. About numerics: it can only be taken to be indicative of the full solution **if** you assume the solution is continuous with regards to initial data (so little approximation errors in numerical analysis won't completely destroy the analysis). The "worse case scenario" will allow this assumption to be false.

Comment: @Willie Wong: I get you now--- you mean that if the singular solutions are dense, a little perturbation will produce a singularity, NS fails at the blowup. But these are PDE's. Suppose there is a countable dense set of singular initial velocity conditions of compact support, indexed by n. It is likely that the large n singular solutions are only singular in tiny regions, so that in terms of L_2 distance, they are close to globally smooth solutions (the L_2 distance can't blow up by energy bound), so that the smooth solutions describe singularity advection, without real loss of predictability.

Comment: @Willie Wong: The NS can only fail to be the complete description at a small collection of singular points and their immediate neighborhoods. It can't be singular in too large a region by energy conservation. The little hypothetical singularities are advected by the gross average smooth flow around them. The obvious fix to smooth out the singularity is to add a hyperviscosity of the form $\nabla^2\nabla^2 v$, which I believe is already proved to regularize the equation completely. If NS has blow ups, you would just get to see the hyperviscosity at some points.

Comment: Why is it _impossible_ that $P \ne NP$ could have a negative answer? If we could show that, then we have shown $P \ne NP$! Also, there is no such thing as "100% sure" in science, unlike in mathematics.

Comment: @mike4ty4: Proof is mathematical certainty, but scientific certainty is about heuristics and common sense. The question P!=NP is equivalent to the statement that given the output of a computation of size N going forward, you can reverse it to guess the initial condition with only polynomial effort in N. But this computation can be embedded in a reversible computation, by introducing spectator waste bits, and the number of waste bits grows as N. To reverse the computation, you need to guess the waste bits, and they have arbitrary complexity, so you need exponential search. That's not a proof.

Comment: So then you're saying it's _probably_ true, not "100% surely true". But that's the same case as with many of these other unresolved conjectures, isn't it? They're _probably_ one of true/false, but may be the other.

Comment: @mike4ty4: I suppose you could say it that way. But heuristics are useful. If I ask you if you scan "pi" looking for places with two consecutive even digits, and find their density, it's going to be 1/4, even though nobody has proved it, because the digits are "random enough" for this to be true. This is the scientific standard of evidence, not mathematical proof. But P!=NP for me is effectively certain. On the other hand, this statement about Navier Stokes is not.

Comment: So what is the reason for considering P!=NP to be "scientifically certain"?

Comment: @mike4ty4: I explained it two comments above--- the bits in a reversible computation can be arbitrarily complex, and there should be no way to compute a subset of them from an arbitrarily small fraction of them. In order to figure them out, you need to guess a sizable fraction of them, which means exponential search. It's actually stronger than "P!=NP", it's that NP complete problems require at least exponential in a fractional power of N search, and perhaps exponential in N search. P!=NP is too weak.

Answer (score 0):

YES! it will have drastic consequences in practice.
N-soliton solutions (general solutions) to the Navier-Stokes d.e. has been recently found. Please see the following publication cited as

R. Meulens , "A note on N-soliton solutions for the viscid incompressible Navier–Stokes differential equation", AIP Advances 12, 015308 (2022) https://doi.org/10.1063/5.0074083

The consequences for physics are then obviously (except of those already listed)

- in aeronautics (and car manufacturing industries):
  -better and faster designs (Will save millions in CAD designs)

- will make expensive wind tunnels up till certain degrees obsolete
- no need for approximation of lift and description of aeronautical processes with statistical coefficients like the lift coefficient, drag coefficient etc. anymore
- better understanding of lift. lift occurrence is now postulated by several theories. None of them suffice exactly. "The causal relationship between lift and acceleration will suffice and will complement all 3 postulates"

- in Astro-physics :
  -better understanding of gravity and galaxy occurrences which are spirals. These are stream-line solutions of the Navier Stokes d.e.

- replacement theory for the general relativity solving the cosmological constant problem.
  -possibly explanation and "bridge-over" to a mechanics for everything (one theory for classic and quantum mechanics and general and special relativity)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

The Answer to this Question is "NO" There is no positive solution. The reason why there can't be a positive solution, is the surface in fluid; It means, no continuity over surface. No viscous forces but, collision and friction.

This helps to understand the cause of the Turbulence; If you avoid to "damage" the fluid to aparts" you avoid turbulence. This "damage" can be caused by cutting edges, but also from pressure shocks. Velocity is only the way to these pressure shocks.

The practical consequences is therefore that ie.

1. Reynolds Number becomes meaningless outside the range where it's fully tested.
2. The Turbines are designed with more attention to continuity laws, ie. [Tests of a turbine using this principle.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Itkf0cZxzG8) According to the Euler's Turbine equations we are having a efficiency of over 100%. This difference comes from the measured angle and measured power. Cause in this machine the Continuity rules are hold, the fluid doesn't damaged and viscous expansion is able to transfer the deceleration of fluid to an usable pressure; bit like in piston pump. The former counter rotating turbines suffered from a sudden pressure drop, as the first runner accelerated the flow and took energy away. This caused heavy turbulence to second runner -> low efficiency.
3. Also the open channel flow can be Finally calculated without magical "Experince-factor". This saves the building costs, as the erodible Turbulence can be avoided. [An example from these structures is here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnRXXhXFkU8&index=6&list=PL489087BF3C5D6131); You can really see how the flow in the middle remains Laminar-alike. There is more videos about the issue in my channel.
4. The aerodynamics of any objects can be made better. Ie. the cars frontal edges might have similar components [as the Bulpous bow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulbous_bow) in ships; reducing drag and wake and thus increasing speed, range, fuel efficiency, and stability. The purpose of this bulp, is obviously to make a clean cut on water.
5. Controlled vortex bursting can reduce the drag, like [decribed in this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/126556/could-the-phenomenon-of-vortex-bursting-be-exploited-to-reduce-wake-turbulence) to be able to do that optimally, the tubulence must be first understood correctly.
6. Please edit and add your own,,,,, Generally it leads to great improvement on efficiency in most everyday products.

[The existince of these surfaces can be proven by optics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/190414/the-optics-of-vortex-in-water-why-there-is-a-bright-ring).

Comment: The question is "would have any practical consequences?" And though I shortly name the thinking path to these consequences, and then even name true results with video or foto, the answer  is voted down. I read the up voted answer, but there wasn't any "practical consequences" named. Not a single one.